# CSS- Why does dropdown menu open horizontally in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

The code works perfectly in Firefox. When you hover over the "Parts & Tools" menu, it opens vertically as it should.
But in Internet Explorer it opens horizontally.
I've tried messing around with the display but I still couldn't identify the problem.
I should point out, the code is written to be responsive to the browser size.

```css
div#Container {
  position: relative;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
.nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.nav ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav ul a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.nav ul a:hover {
  background: red;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
.nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav ul li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  top: 45px;
}
div#middle {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parts &amp; Tools</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Parts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the "display:inline-block" on the list item, inline means horizontal, so instead of

```
.nav ul li
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

you want

```
.nav ul li
{
  display: block;
}
```